# joomla 1.5 meta info not coming from my website

Tags: php, joomla, meta

My website got hacked. After that I have cleaned my whole code and db. When I search website with my keyword on google the result shows as hacked page. Link shows right but meta info and google cached page is not right.

Comment: If you've been hacked you need to wipe your server and reinstall from a backup.

Comment: This probably belongs to ServerFault.SX.

Answer (score 0):

Use webmaster tools and submit a request to Google to review this again. You will have to make sure that the website is indeed clean. There is a good guide on how to clean the site here - https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced